# Cannot set cell value AND formula, one overwrites the other

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an apps script which attempt to set a cell's formula, but as soon as it sets it, the value of the cell also gets changed to the formula. Is there a way to keep the value after calling range.setFormula()?

here is the code

```
//Function called when cell value changes when chosen from drop down or changed manually
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.range;
  var managerName = r.getValue();
  // This call to rowOfManager returns a row number in another sheet
  var row = rowOfManager(managerName);
  r.setFormula(prefix + sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue() + suffix);
}
```

I have omitted the prefix and suffix values as they in themselves are not important. The formula does change properly, but also does the cell value and I don't want the cell value to change at all.

I have tried to add

```
r.setValue(managerName);
```

Before or after the call to setFormula, but when it is after, the cell value is correct and the formula disappears and gets set to the value.

This is all very frustrating and I am sure I am just missing something rather silly somewhere,

Your help is very much appreciated

Regards
Crouz

Comment: can you show the formula your inserting before and after `setFormula` not sure to understand what's your problem but perhaps your missing a `=` sign at the beginning of your string

Comment: The formula is =IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/(SHEET_ID_GOES_HERE)/edit#gid=6510476955","Sales Date!g1

Comment: and is this the value of the cell before or after `setFormula()` ?

Comment: `The formula does change properly, but also does the cell value and I don't want the cell value to change at all.` Lol. Why? Why do you want the formula there at all?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the basic way that Google Sheets works

A cell could contain a value (scalar value), a member of an array of values, or a formula, if a cell contains a formula it will display the formula result.